# Problem installing toolchain recipes in iOs

Tags: ios, python-3.x, kivy

I am trying to package a python app in iOS.
The app is very simple with just 1 line:

```
from firebase import firebase
```

I follow the instruction from this link:

```
https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
```

Everything is good. I use Xcode to push the app to a virtual Simulator. I need to install a recipe pycrypto. So I move to the kivy-ios folder and run the following code as instructed:

```
sudo ./toolchain.py build pycrypto
```

It failed with the following error (or warning):

```
hcaos-iMac:kivy-ios hcao$ sudo ./toolchain.py build pycrypto
[INFO    ] Building with 4 processes, where supported
[INFO    ] Want to build ['pycrypto']
[INFO    ] Loaded recipe pycrypto (depends of ['python', 'openssl'], optional are [])
[INFO    ] Loaded recipe python (depends of [u'python3'], optional are [])
[INFO    ] Loaded recipe openssl (depends of [], optional are [])
[INFO    ] Loaded recipe python3 (depends of ['hostpython3', 'libffi', 'openssl'], optional are [])
[INFO    ] Loaded recipe hostpython3 (depends of [], optional are ['openssl'])
[INFO    ] Loaded recipe libffi (depends of [], optional are [])
[INFO    ] Build order is ['libffi', 'openssl', 'hostpython3', u'python3', 'python', 'pycrypto']
[INFO    ] Recipe order is ['libffi', 'openssl', 'hostpython3', 'python3', 'pycrypto']
[INFO    ] Include dir added: {arch.arch}/ffi
[INFO    ] Include dir added: {arch.arch}/openssl
[INFO    ] Global: hostpython located at /Users/hcao/Desktop/kivyios-python3/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/python
[INFO    ] Global: hostpgen located at /Users/hcao/Desktop/kivyios-python3/kivy-ios/dist/hostpython3/bin/pgen
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Download libffi. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Extract libffi. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Build_all libffi. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Download openssl. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Extract openssl. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Build_all openssl. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Download hostpython3. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Extract hostpython3. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Build_all hostpython3. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Download python3. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Extract python3. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Build_all python3. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Download pycrypto. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Extract pycrypto. Ignoring
[DEBUG   ] Cached result: Build_all pycrypto. Ignoring
```

I'm using Mojave in VirtualBox, python3. 
I have no idea why everything is "ignoring".
My app can be packaged successfully in Linux for android.
I am not a Mac user at all. Please help me resolve the issue.
Anything is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like pycrypto was already compiled from a previous build, and so it didn't do anything.

After compiling a new recipe, you need to update your project to include the new compiled recipe into your project with the command:

```
./toolchain.py update myproject
```

Also, please don't use sudo at all, we never ask or need for administrator rights.

Comment: Thank you so much. You show me how to build and update project with a new recipe. However, I still ran into problem afterward. So I started a new project with just python3. And now I can't build pycrypto. Would you please be kind enough to look at the link````https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864387/unable-to-build-pycrypto-recipe-in-python3-toolchain````